# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2] in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I try to run coil `import coil.compose.rememberAsyncImagePainter` so that I can run
`val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = curr.images.random()) Image(painter = painter, contentDescription = "image", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth)`
I get this error:
`A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MovieApp'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

This is my build.gradle. Can anyone think of where could my problem be?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.1.1'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
}
```

Comment: Just remove the brackets. `implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2" `

Comment: it's the same problem

Comment: You are using the top level build.gradle file in the root instead of the build.gradle I'm the app/module

Answer (score 1):

You are using the top level `build.gradle` (in the root folder) to add the dependencies instead of the `build.gradle` in the app/module folder.